# Firefox 24 inappropriately applies css on dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

I have a page with a styled table. The table can start with or without rows in the TBODY.
If a row is present initially, the original table plus any content dynamically added (via jquery $.get and appending to the TBODY) will display correctly.

If there is NO rows initially in the TBODY then the dynamically added rows will display but without border css that was defined on the table as a whole. Adding borders directly to the dynamic rows will not work because they are (correctly) being overridden by the css applied at a table level (overridden correctly, but still not displaying)

If I ensure a dummy row is present initially then hide it through display:none, then the moment that row is hidden, the borders on the dynamically added rows disappear.

This problem is not exhibited on IE9 or Chrome. Any ideas, and anyone involved with Firefox want to submit it as a bug note?

Comment: Could you please share your HTML, CSS, etc.?  You will have a much better chance at getting a helpful answer when we don't have to guess exactly what is going on in your code.

Comment: @user2307922 did you get the figured out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like one of two things:

- You have invalid markup and the different browsers are handling the error differently.
- You have encountered a legit Firefox bug and ought to let the good peoples at Mozilla know. You can file and track your own bug reports [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/index.cgi).

I would triple check your markup both before and after the table gets populated, triple check the markup in the ajax response as well; then if it still looks like a bug, file a report and wait for the update.

If waiting for the update is just going to take to long for your circumstance, it may be time to find a hack.

Comment: +1 for the invalid markup check. I've found that browsers can exhibit unpredictable behaviour when using javascript to manipulate DOM content, if the content you are adding is invalid in some way. I'd suggest in addition to checking the markup before and after, that the OP also check the HTML that is returned from the ajax request.